# Is it shots or shoots by "name of the photographer"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Hey I'm a young photographer and I want to create a website to display my portfoilio. I want to name it:

> shots/shoots by - followed by my name

and I don't know what term is correct here.

On the website there will be uploads of multiple photosessions as a whole and not single picture uploads

Answer (score 2):

While "shoot" (as a noun) can refer to a photo session, it refers to the session itself, not to the photos produced, in my experience. "Shoots by X" on a website will just look like a mistake (unless it is a diary of the sessions themselves).

Only "shots" is possible for the photos themselves. If you want to bring out the organisation into sessions, I think you'll need something like "albums" or "collections".

You might just about get away with "photosessions by ... ": using the full word will stop it misdirecting readers, and I think people will guess that it means "The photos from photosessions by ...".

Comment: *Photo shoots* is actually [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=photo+shoots%2C+photo+sessions%2C+photosessions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphoto%20shoots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphoto%20sessions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphotosessions%3B%2Cc0), at least informally. And *photo session* is generally an open-form noun, not closed.

Comment: Fair comment, @JasonBassford. But "shoots" on its own won't work.